# Displaying zeroes in COBOL

Tags: encoding, cobol, gnucobol

I'm new to COBOL and our latest training activity is we will try to get an output of three items like this:

1. 0000/2013
2. 00012345
3. 12345**

I have tried with my code below but it clearly does not give me the output I want. It does not display zeroes.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.

PROGRAM-ID. ACTIVITY4.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

DATA DIVISION.

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

01 NUM1 PIC z(4)9(4) VALUE 2013.
01 NUM2 PIC Z(3)9(5) VALUE 12345.
01 NUM3 PIC 9(5) VALUE 12345.
01 E-NUM1 PIC *(2)9 VALUE 0.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.

DISPLAY-VALUES.

DISPLAY-ZEROES.

MOVE E-NUM1 TO NUM3.

 DISPLAY "1) "NUM1.

 DISPLAY "2) "NUM2.

 DISPLAY "3) "NUM3.

 STOP RUN.
```

Comment: For completeness you should edit your question to include the output you actually get with your code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like Activity 4 is about formatting data for output. You need to produce:

```
0000/2013
00012345
12345**
```

The first requires the insertion of a slash. COBOL has a slash insertion symbol, '/'. The second is to ensure no zero-suppression, which is the behaviour when a PIC 9(n) field is output, so nothing really to do other than get the length right. The third apparently draws you to the "*" replacement edit field, which is the intention of the question I guess, but the * editing symbol replaces leading zeros only.

One simple way to get the trailing asterisks is to use the data-definition. Define a group item, which is what you will DISPLAY. Subordinate to that, define your number (PIC 9(5)) and follow it immediately with a FILLER (named field if you like) PIC XX which has a VALUE of `"**"` (or ALL `"*"`, a little extreme for a two-byte field though).

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.

PROGRAM-ID. ACTIVITY4.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

DATA DIVISION.

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

01 NUM1 PIC 9(4)/9(4).
01 NUM2 PIC 9(8).
01 NUM3-OUT. 
    05  NUM3 PIC 9(5). 
    05  FILLER PIC XX VALUE "**".
```

PROCEDURE DIVISION.

```
DISPLAY-VALUES.

DISPLAY-ZEROES.
 MOVE 1234 TO NUM1

 DISPLAY "1) " 
             ">"
             NUM1
             "<"
 MOVE 12345 TO NUM2

 DISPLAY "2) "
             ">"
             NUM2
             "<"
 MOVE 12345 TO NUM3
 DISPLAY "3) "
             ">"
             NUM3-OUT
             "<"

 STOP RUN
 .
```

I have never put a VALUE on an edited field. The editing is carried out when the field is a target of a COBOL verb. In the COBOLs I use this would not effect the edit, it would just have that literal value. I don't know about GNU OpenCOBOL (formerly OpenCOBOL).

Answer (score 0):

Drop the Z when declaring the numbers.

Z suppresses leading zeros in a number in COBOL.

Simply changing your variable declarations to:

```
01 NUM1 PIC 9(8) VALUE 00002013.
01 NUM2 PIC 9(8) VALUE 00012345.
```

(You don't actually need the preceding zeroes in the number, they're just there to show you the whole PIC.)

Please see [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_clause) for a more detailed description on picture statements and a quick summary of the different character modifiers and what they do.

I didn't catch the other issue at first, however the other variable you created should be

```
01 E-NUM1 PIC 9(2) VALUE 0.
```

Comment: it still does not work i have tried every compile option still the same

Comment: The only other change to your code I had to make was to the third variable declaration, (Where you declare *(2)9).  I'll update my answer to reflect this.  You should be using the -x and -free (-free is optional, but nice) arguments when compiling.

Also, you say you want your output for #3 to be 12345, but you move a 0 into the variable where you hold 12345, was this just to play with things?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `12345**` issue: If nothing else works, you can concatenate the number to the asterisks with a `STRING` like this:

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

01 NUM3 PIC X(7).
01 NUM3-NUMBERS PIC 9(5) VALUE 12345.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.

STRING NUM3-NUMBERS "**" DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO NUM3.
DISPLAY "3) "NUM3.
```

What this code does is adding 2 asterisks at the end of your number.
(but your NUM3 is now an alphanumeric picture instead a numeric one).

Another thing i just found in an old cobol book here is the `*` Check Protection Character. I have never tried it but here it states it should be used this way:

```
01 NUM3 PIC 9(5)*(2).
```

Give it a try!

Comment: The book may say that the check-protection only works on leading zeros. Mine does. I doubt any COBOL compiler performs suppression of trailing zeros, even if the value had trailing zeros - which it doesn't. What do you feel would be the advantage of using STRING over just having it sitting there all the time in WORKING-STORAGE?